What is this device that is sticking out of the ground?
A desert rat approaches a device protruding from the ground, which is
making a breathing sound. The rat starts digging, but then a Fedaykin
fighter whispers.:


Fighter: Hey, get out of here. Go.

What is this device that is sticking out of the ground?

If you watch literally seconds later, you find out.

It's a sand snorkel. You use them for breathing while hiding under the sand, from the elements or from an enemy that is approaching.
Paul and Jessica use one in the novel Dune. Apparently it's a bit higher tech than just a mundane snorkel since it seem to have some sort of pump built into it, and a filter to keep out fine particles of sand.

The undemanding emptiness of her words helped restore some of his
calm. His mind focused on the storm as he had seen it begin through
the transparent end of their stilltent–cold dribbles of sand crossing
the basin, then runnels and tails furrowing the sky. He had looked up
to a rock spire, seen it change shape under the blast, becoming a low,
Cheddar-colored wedge. Sand funneled into their basin had shadowed the
sky with dull curry, then blotted out all light as the tent was
covered.
Tent bows had creaked once as they accepted the pressure, then–silence
broken only by the dim bellows wheezing of their sand snorkel pumping
air from the surface.

